# toggleclass active doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the menu to work like this. When you click Main1 it becomes active and the list will show, when you click it again the list will hide. When Main1 is active and you click Main2, then the Main1 should be inactive and Main2 active.
But my Javascript doesn't seem to make it work well. It makes the Main1 inactive when you click Main2 and the other way, but if you click on any of the active Main it doesn't become incactive. Please help

```
    <div class="directory-section-list">
    <ul  class="list_item">
            <li class="li_lvl lvl0" id="bx_1847241719_2">Main1</li>
              <ul>
            <li class=""><span class="li_lvl lvl1">1.5-4.5</span>
              <ul>
            <li><a href="/directory/autoloader/1-1-8-tons/fd-15/58-fd-15.html">FD 15</a></li>
            <li><a href="/directory/autoloader/1-1-8-tons/fd-18/59-fd-18.html">FD 18</a></li>
              </ul>
              </ul>

     <ul  class="list_item">
            <li class="li_lvl lvl0" id="bx_1847241719_2">Main2</li>
              <ul>
            <li class=""><span class="li_lvl lvl1">1.5-4.5</span>
              <ul>                          
           <li><a href="/directory/autoloader/1-1-8-tons/fd-15/58-fd-15.html">FD 15</a></li>
           <li><a href="/directory/autoloader/1-1-8-tons/fd-18/59-fd-18.html">FD 18</a></li>
          </ul>
              </ul >
             </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(' .list_item .lvl0').click(function(){
    $(".list_item.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
});

$(' .list_item .lvl1').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: try adding $(".list_item .active").removeClass("active"); instead of $(".list_item.active").removeClass("active");

Comment: @VidyaSMasani when I do .list_item .active then I manage to toggle the active class, but if Main1 is active and I click Main2, the Main1 remains active, i want it to become inactive.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```js
$('.list_item .lvl0').click(function(){
 $('.directory-section-list .active').removeClass('active');
  
 if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active'))
 {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
 }
 else
 {
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
 } 
});

$('.list_item .lvl1').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: it is still the same. My Main1 remains active if I click it again.. I want the main1 to become inactive once I click it when it is active.

Comment: now Main1 active gets removed if you click it again. that is cool. but if Main1 is active and I click Main2 I want the class active to be removed from Main1

Comment: Now I think its fine. Pls check

Comment: no it is not (((. If Main1 is active and I click it again it won't close((. https://jsfiddle.net/2ff6cuw9/

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

HTML

```
<div class="directory-section-list">
    <ul class="list_item">
        <li class="li_lvl lvl0" id="bx_1847241719_2">Main1</li>
        <ul>
            <li class=""><span class="li_lvl lvl1">1.5-4.5</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/directory/autoloader/1-1-8-tons/fd-15/58-fd-15.html">FD 15</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/directory/autoloader/1-1-8-tons/fd-18/59-fd-18.html">FD 18</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list_item">
        <li class="li_lvl lvl1" id="bx_1847241719_2">Main2</li>
        <ul>
            <li class=""><span class="li_lvl lvl1">1.5-4.5</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/directory/autoloader/1-1-8-tons/fd-15/58-fd-15.html">FD 15</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/directory/autoloader/1-1-8-tons/fd-18/59-fd-18.html">FD 18</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Java Script

```
$(' .list_item .lvl0').click(function () {
   $(' .list_item .lvl1').parent().removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
});

$(' .list_item .lvl1').click(function () {
   $(' .list_item .lvl0').parent().removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: It is still the same unfortunately. The Main1 doesn't close when you click Main2

Comment: @AlvinOfori-Adjei but the active class is applying properly.Can you create a fiddler to debug the issue

Comment: If the Main1 is currently active and you click it again it doesn't become inactive.

Comment: Well now I can close Main1, but if I click Main2 when Main1 is active the Main1 doesn't become inactive.

Comment: @AlvinOfori-Adjei click Main2 when Main1 is active ,then from Main1 the  `active` class get removed . is the way you need I guess

Comment: from my end it's working  also you can try this `$('.directory-section-list .active').removeClass('active');` remove both `$(' .list_item .lvl1').parent().removeClass("active");` and `$(' .list_item .lvl0').parent().removeClass("active");` and replace with the above one.It should work for you

Comment: well yes this is what i need, but if i have Main up to 10, I must write lvl1 lvl2 lvl3 up to 10?? in JS?

Comment: oh good! but I can't seem to click child categories. When I click them the Main1 closes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.maindiv').hide();
 
 $( "button" ).click(function() {
  $('.maindiv[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').toggle("fade",300);
 });
});
```

```css
div {
 background-color: green;
 color: white;
 width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button class="show" data-link="main1">Main1</button>
<button class="show" data-link="main2">Main2</button>
<div>
 <div class="maindiv" data-link="main1">
   <h1>This is main1</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="maindiv" data-link="main2">
   <h1>This is main2</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well yes, but I want the Main1 to become inactive if you clic it again. In your example if you click main1 again it appears constantly.

Comment: So simply you want to disable the button?

Comment: not to disable but the menu in Main1 should vanish when you click it again. If Main1 has class active then when you click it again it should remove class active. When Main1 has class active and you click Main2 the Main1 class active should be removed as well

Comment: I've updated the code this time i'm using jquery-ui toggle effect.

Comment: now when you click Main2 the Main 1 should go off if it is on

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but your HTML List had a couple of errors the

```
<li class=""><span class="li_lvl lvl1">1.5-4.5</span>
```

will never be closed...

its all about the HTML Structure - i've done another change -> check the HTML Structure of this JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marco_rensch/hzu76hgt/32/

Comment: you have not added Jquery library in your fiddler

Comment: @Proximate ok, yes i had a mistake in my code. thanks. your example is just right but when you click main1 it becomes green alright. I want to click Main1 Again so that the green dissapears.

Comment: @Proximate almost, but if Main1 is green and you click Main2, the Main1 should go off. It is like your first example but now I need to combine the two of the examples.

Comment: @Proximate click Main1, it should become green. Click Main1 again it should go off. Click Main2 when Main1 is green, the Main1 should go off and Main2 should become green

Comment: @Alvin Ofory-Adjei --> please check my answer again - now it should work for you ;-)

Comment: @Proximate no, it doesn't work. you did it as the first time. but this is not what i want. read it carefully. Click Main1, it should become green. Click Main1 Again it should go OFF. Click Main2 WHEN Main1 is Green, the Main1 should go Off and Main2 should become green

Comment: yes - main1 toggle and disable main2 if active / main2 toggle and disable main1 if active....

http://jsfiddle.net/marco_rensch/hzu76hgt/32/ ;-)

Comment: @Proximate very very good! but when I click the child categories like FD 15 under Main1 the active class toggles. It should not toggle when I click the child category.

Answer (score 0):

Well Thank you all for your help. I managed to do it taking some of your examples and making it work my own way. Thank you again. I will post the Javascript fix.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('.li_lvl').click(function () {

            if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
            }
            else {
               $('.directory-section-list .active').removeClass('active');
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            }
        });
```

This will toggle class active of the parent .li_lvl which is the ul.list_item. If parent has class active it will remove class active. If any other list_item will have class active whilst you click on the other list_item, it will remove class active on the other list_item and make class active on the list_item you clicked.